# XAML Nested ScrollView leaves scrolling to parent

Tags: c#, wpf, scrollview, platform-specific

I have an app with a structure like this (where the `Frame` has the contents set to a `Page` eg `MyPage`:

#### MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window ... Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <ScrollViewer VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Frame NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" Source="Page1.xaml"/>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

#### MyPage.xaml

```xml
<Page ...>
    <Grid Background="GhostWhite">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="300"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Background="Pink">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="0">Title</TextBlock>
            <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Rectangle Margin="10" Fill="Red" Width="250" Height="100"/>
                    <Rectangle Margin="10" Fill="Red" Width="250" Height="100"/>
                    <Rectangle Margin="10" Fill="Red" Width="250" Height="100"/>
                    <Rectangle Margin="10" Fill="Red" Width="250" Height="100"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Which in visual studio, the page renders like this, with the scrollbar inside the left panel, which is what I want it to look like:

[image: Page preview]

However, what actually ends up happening when I compile is is the page's `ScrollView`is expanding to take up all the space of its contents, and the `ScrollView`from the main window is the one that is showing the scrollbar. Like this:

[image]

## How can I get the inner `ScrollView` to not grow past its parent grid?

I know I could give it a fixed height, but that isn't what I want, and I have tried wrapping the `ScrollView` in a `Grid` and binding the height of the `ScrollView`to the that `Grid`'s `Height` and `ActualHeight` properties, as well as to the same properties of the `RowDefinition` of the parent `Grid`

Comment: You might want to try binding with the `ViewportHeight` [(Docu)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.scrollviewer.viewportheight) of the `ScrollViewer` rather than the `ActualHeight`, which includes the non visible part.

Comment: do you need the scrollviewer in the mainwindow? without it, it works as you want it to be.

Comment: @Blechdose I do, the contents of the frame change dynamically, and if it overflows (most pages do) then it needs to have a scroll bar (i dont want to have to define the scrollview in every page)

Comment: @FlorianH. the `ViewportHeight` is a read only property. I cant set that to anything. If you mean to bind something else to that, I dont know what you mean, could you please elaborate a little, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I've found a solution. I realized that in order to limit the side panel height and have it always visible, I would have to make sure the page never got bigger than the frame. To do that I had to bind the height of the root `Grid` to the `ScrollView`'s `ViewportHeight` property. I already had a property in the `MyPage` class which was the frame (used for navigating purposes) like this:

#### MyPage.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class MyPage : Page {
    public Frame Frame { get; }
    // ...
}
```

So in the XAML I was able to bind the height like this:

#### MyPage.xaml

```xml
<Page ...>
    <Grid Height="{Binding Frame.Parent.ViewportHeight}">
        <!-- ... -->
    </Grid>
</Page>
```